# How to install soci db library with vcpkg on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite, cmake, soci

I'm trying to install `soci[sqlite3]` or even `soci[sqlite3,boost]` (according to [external information about dependencies in vcpkg](https://vcpkg.roundtrip.dev/ports/soci)) on Linux with VCPKG. Unfortunately it is not working as it should. I tried to do its on separate environment, because of that I've created docker instance:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --network=host -v $(pwd):/home/ --workdir /home --name='ubuntu_test' ubuntu:22.04
# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y --no-install-recommends
# apt-get install g++ git cmake curl zip unzip tar ca-certificates make pkg-config --no-install-recommends  -y
```

Then I've downloaded and built `vcpkg`:

```
# git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git --depth=1
# ./vcpkg/bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
```

The next step was to install `soci[sqlite3]` with vcpkg, so I used command:

```
# ./vcpkg/vcpkg install 'soci[sqlite3]'
```

after succesfull installation I saw output:

```
...
  find_package(SOCI CONFIG REQUIRED)
  target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE SOCI::soci_core_static SOCI::soci_empty_static SOCI::soci_sqlite3_static)
```

Then I tried to get CMake argument by caling:

```
# ./vcpkg/vcpkg integrate install
Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.
CMake projects should use: "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

Then I use simplest `CMakeLists.txt` (took [from official `vcpkg` tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/examples/installing-and-using-packages) modified as suggested by `vcpkg`):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Learning_VCPKG LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(SOCI CONFIG REQUIRED)

if (SOCI_FOUND)
    message("Soci found: ${SOCI_INCLUDE_DIRS} and ${SOCI_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
endif ()

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE SOCI::soci_core_static SOCI::soci_empty_static SOCI::soci_sqlite3_static)
```

Then I build & compile:

```
# cmake . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
Soci found:  and 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home
root@agh-legion:/home# make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Learning_VCPKG.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Learning_VCPKG
/usr/bin/ld: vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsoci_sqlite3.a(vector-into-type.cpp.o): in function `soci::sqlite3_vector_into_type_backend::post_fetch(bool, soci::indicator*)':
/home/vcpkg/buildtrees/soci/src/v4.0.3-7f07d34610.clean/src/backends/sqlite3/vector-into-type.cpp:260: undefined reference to `soci::details::parse_std_tm(char const*, tm&)'
/usr/bin/ld: vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsoci_sqlite3.a(standard-into-type.cpp.o): in function `soci::sqlite3_standard_into_type_backend::post_fetch(bool, bool, soci::indicator*)':
/home/vcpkg/buildtrees/soci/src/v4.0.3-7f07d34610.clean/src/backends/sqlite3/standard-into-type.cpp:139: undefined reference to `soci::details::parse_std_tm(char const*, tm&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Learning_VCPKG.dir/build.make:102: Learning_VCPKG] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/Learning_VCPKG.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

And here is code (inspired from [official example](https://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/master/quickstart/)):

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <soci/soci.h>
#include <soci/sqlite3/soci-sqlite3.h>
#include <string>

using namespace soci;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try {
        soci::session sql(sqlite3, "test.db");

        sql << "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employees("
               "ID     INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
               "name   TEXT            NOT NULL,"
               "Age   INT             NOT NULL,"
               "Address  TEXT,"
               "Salary REAL);";
        sql << "INSERT INTO Employees (ID, name, Age, Address, Salary) VALUES (1, 'Tadeusz', 24, 'Krakow', 2000.01 ); ";
        sql << "INSERT INTO Employees (ID, name, Age, Address, Salary) VALUES (2, 'Symeon', 25, 'Texas', 15000.00 ); ";
        sql << "INSERT INTO Employees (ID, name, Age, Address, Salary) VALUES (3, 'Rodion', 23, 'Norway', 20000.00 );";

        int count;
        sql << "select count(*) from Employees", into(count);

        cout << "We have " << count << " entries in the Employees table.\n";
    } catch (exception const& e) {
        cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

I checked compilation command (`VERBOSE` flag to makefile):

```
# make VERBOSE=True
/usr/bin/c++ CMakeFiles/Learning_VCPKG.dir/main.cpp.o -o Learning_VCPKG  vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsoci_core.a vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsoci_empty.a vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsoci_sqlite3.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsqlite3.a
```

And what is strange - after changing compilation command it worked!:

```
# /usr/bin/c++ CMakeFiles/Learning_VCPKG.dir/main.cpp.o vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsoci_core.a vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsoci_empty.a vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsoci_sqlite3.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsqlite3.a -o Learning_VCPKG -L./vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/ -lsoci_core
root@agh-legion:/home# ./Learning_VCPKG 
We have 3 entries in the Employees table.
```

To make sure I checked compiled libraries and it really contains missing symbols:

```
# nm -C  vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/debug/lib/libsoci_core.a | grep "parse_std_tm"
00000000000002bd T soci::details::parse_std_tm(char const*, tm&)
```

**As You noticed there are two possibilities:

1. I am doing something wrong (more probably solutions) - please help
2. VCPKG is buggy and does not know how to compile C++ program? (less probably)**

To provide all necessarily information here is version of libraries and vcpkg:

```
# ./vcpkg/vcpkg list
soci:x64-linux                                    4.0.3#1             SOCI database access library
soci[sqlite3]:x64-linux                                               Build sqlite3 backend
sqlite3:x64-linux                                 3.43.0              SQLite is a software library that implements a s...
sqlite3[json1]:x64-linux                                              Enable JSON functionality for sqlite3
vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-linux                      2022-02-06#1        
vcpkg-cmake:x64-linux                             2023-05-04 
# ./vcpkg/vcpkg version
vcpkg package management program version 2023-09-15-ac02a9f660977426b8ec6392919fbb1d51b10998
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was bug in soci port for VCPKG, it was fixed in [new version](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/commit/64c330e2e7c616c654a766354131ea0ad404917d) ([link to issue request](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/34168) and [link to PR](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/34327)).

Now after running commands provided in question VCPKG is printing:

```
    find_package(soci CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE $<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:SOCI::soci_core>,SOCI::soci_core,SOCI::soci_core_static>)

    # Linking specific backends (enabled: sqlite3)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE $<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:SOCI::soci_<BACKEND>,SOCI::soci_<BACKEND>,SOCI::soci_<BACKEND>_static>)
```

In the code You need to replace `<BACKEND>` with backend_name (in the question with `sqlite3`). So correct way of linking in CMakeLists.txt is:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE $<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:SOCI::soci_core>,SOCI::soci_core,SOCI::soci_core_static>)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE $<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:SOCI::soci_sqlite3>,SOCI::soci_sqlite3,SOCI::soci_sqlite3_static>)
```